# Highstock lineWidth

Tags: highcharts

I want to set my chart lineWidth but it has a strange behavior.

On mouse over it turns into lineWidth:2(default) and when mouse outs it turns into my lineWidth setting.

```
  plotOptions:{
            series:{
                lineWidth: 5
            }
        },
```

What's the problem?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bahar_Agi/HePx3/2/
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is. As I said, you can configure the state as described in the API.

See http://jsfiddle.net/HePx3/4/

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineWidth: 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the chart has states. In this case a hover state with a default value of lineWidth:2px.

You can disable the state or configure it, see: http://jsfiddle.net/HePx3/3/

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

For API, see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.states.hover